# Using seaborn, how can I draw a line of my choice across my scatterplot?

Tags: python, matplotlib, seaborn

I want to be able to draw a line of my specification across a plot generated in seaborn.  The plot I chose was JointGrid, but any scatterplot will do.  I suspect that seaborn maybe doesn't make it easy to do this?

Here is the code plotting the data (dataframes from the Iris dataset of petal length and petal width):

```
import seaborn as sns
iris = sns.load_dataset("iris")    
grid = sns.JointGrid(iris.petal_length, iris.petal_width, space=0, size=6, ratio=50)
    grid.plot_joint(plt.scatter, color="g")
```

[image]

If you take this graph from the iris dataset, how can I draw a line of my choice across it?  For example, a line of negative slope might separate the clusters, and positive slope might run across them.

Answer (score 35, accepted):

It appears that you have imported `matplotlib.pyplot` as `plt` to obtain `plt.scatter` in your code. You can just use the matplotlib functions to plot the line:

```
import seaborn as sns
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

iris = sns.load_dataset("iris")    
grid = sns.JointGrid(iris.petal_length, iris.petal_width, space=0, size=6, ratio=50)
grid.plot_joint(plt.scatter, color="g")
plt.plot([0, 4], [1.5, 0], linewidth=2)
```

[image]

Comment: is there a way not to physically put the numbers for each point of the line? I mean if I want a vertical line in 2 how can i make it with seaborn?

Comment: You can use `axvline` for vertical lines which span the whole axis.

Answer (score 10):

By creating a `JointGrid` in seaborn, you have created three axes, the main `ax_joint`, and the two marginal axes.

To plot something else on the joint axes, we can access the joint grid using `grid.ax_joint`, and then create plot objects on there as you would with any other `matplotlib` `Axes` object.

For example:

```
import seaborn as sns
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

iris = sns.load_dataset("iris")    
grid = sns.JointGrid(iris.petal_length, iris.petal_width, space=0, size=6, ratio=50)

# Create your scatter plot
grid.plot_joint(plt.scatter, color="g")

# Create your line plot.
grid.ax_joint.plot([0,4], [1.5,0], 'b-', linewidth = 2)
```

As an aside, you can also access the marginal axes of a `JointGrid` in a similar way:

```
grid.ax_marg_x.plot(...)
grid.ax_marg_y.plot(...)
```