# Seaborn: how to add arbitrary lines/textframes to clarify chart?

Tags: python, matplotlib, seaborn

Assume the Seaborn MWE below ([code credits this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36146684/using-seaborn-how-can-i-draw-a-line-of-my-choice-across-my-scatterplot)). This produce the picture below (ex red part).

**How can I add arbitrary framed text boxes, and fancy (arrow) lines, to clarify a plot**, for example the red part in the screenshot below?

**How to add the red part?**

[image]

**MWE:**

```
import seaborn as sns
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
iris = sns.load_dataset("iris")
grid = sns.JointGrid(iris.petal_length, iris.petal_width, space=0, size=6, ratio=50)
grid.plot_joint(plt.scatter, color="g")
grid.ax_joint.plot([0,4], [1.5,0], 'b-', linewidth = 2)
grid.savefig("test.png")
```

Comment: Use the underlying matplotlib functions : http://matplotlib.org/users/text_intro.html